# C# .NET 6.0 How to redirect an unauthorized user to an unauthorizedpage

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, .net-6.0

I would like to redirect the unauthorized user to a unauthorizedpage. Authorization is Roles based. For example [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] I'm looking for a general solution. I don't want to write a redirect in every controllor/endpoint. I'm using Windows Auth with the Negotiate protocol.

I'm using the AuthorizeAttribute. When the user is unauthorized for a view then the application shows a blank HTML page to the user.

I tried multiple CustomAttributes, Configure AccesDeniedPaths, HandleUnauthorizedRequest. But every way ended in a blank HTML page.

I hope someone has an solution.

Comment: If you have a site master, or some other page that is included in every one (or even just put a class/function call at top of every page worse case) then have that check permissions and redirect to empty page.

Answer (score 2):

**CustomAuthorizeAttribute**

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Roles { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //if user isn't logged in.
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity == null || !filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Unauthorized/");
        }

        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        //Check user rights here
        if (!user.IsInRole(Roles))
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/Unauthorized/");
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {


        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET has a defualt `[Authorize]` attribute which you can add to an arbitrary action.

Eg:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Classes>>> GetClasses()
 {
   return await _context.Classes.ToListAsync();
 }
```

This will by default redirect the user to the login page if an unauthorized user tries to access a forbidden page.

However, if you want to redirect to a custom page. You could try writing a custom filter attribute like this.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity == null || !filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + "?returnUrl=" +
                filterContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl));
            }

            //Check user rights here
            if (userNotRight)
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 302;
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
    }
```

and use it in a controller like this,

```
[HttpGet]
[CustomAuthorize]
 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Classes>>> GetClasses()
 {
   return await _context.Classes.ToListAsync();
 }
```

If you would like to authorize based on roles for the custom filter attribute. You could either

*1. write a custom authorize attribute and add it along with the filter attribute.*

```
public class AuthorizeAdmin : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            // The user is not authenticated
            return false;
        }

        var user = httpContext.User;
        if (user.IsInRole("Admin")) // Your desired role
        {
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[CustomAttribute]
[AuthorizeAdmin]
 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Classes>>> GetClasses()
 {
   return await _context.Classes.ToListAsync();
 }
```

*2. you could directly check it along with the custom filter attribute*

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        // Check if is in "Admin" role
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            // The user is not authenticated
            return false;
        }

        var user = httpContext.User;
        if (user.IsInRole("Admin")) // Your desired role
        {
            
        
            public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity == null || !filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                 {
                        filterContext.Result = new 
      RedirectResult(System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl 
                        + "?returnUrl=" +
                
 filterContext.HttpContext.Server.UrlEncode(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl));
                 }

                 //Check user rights here
                 if (userNotRight)
                 {
                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 302;
                    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                 }
        }
        }
    }
```

controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[CustomAttribute]
 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Classes>>> GetClasses()
 {
   return await _context.Classes.ToListAsync();
 }
```

Comment: [CustomAuthorize] action filter attribute credits: https://itecnote.com/tecnote/asp-net-mvc-authorize-attribute-redirect-to-custom-no-rights-page/

Comment: It's looking fine. What do I need to do when I want to Authorize based on roles. Like [CustomAttribute(Roles = "Users")]

Comment: I have edited the answer with a relevant answer to your comment. @GuyonM

Comment: Thnx for the help. I found what I need. I placed a new post with the solution.

Comment: Thats great! happy to help (: